# How to add steps while any software deployment?

Tags: java

Using Java (with Eclipse) and Tomcat server I have developed a project.

The way I will deploy this software will be just copy and paste the classes files and project to tomcat-->webapps folder and then copy this tomcat to client's PC then client will start tomcat and will open browser with given URL.

Now my question is while installing any kind of software, we found some steps like...first page...like showing information of software, then accept terms and conditions, next is browse folder where to install ..etc ...then installation progress and finally Finish step.

So how do I achieve this...I had tried by search also but didn't get any results
will somebody tell how to customize such software installation with such fixed steps. What should I use for same?

Comment: what you must have in mind is that web applications are different from desktop applications, so you don't install a web application in each customer computer. You just do it in your server and the client must connect to it by using a browser.

Comment: I have seen scripts that make some "installation steps" on the server, but thats mostly PHP I think..setting up database tables and some other stuff. I've never seen that with a java war or ear. Sounds silly, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean installation wizard like you typically see on Windows you should use one of the available tools for setup creation.

Take a look on [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html), and others or read this discussion: [Multiplatform Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029079/multiplatform-installer)

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative of what you are doing could be package all your class, jsps and other resources into a `war` file. And you'll have some sort of installation file. With this file you can now procede to install it inside tomcat or any other compatible server.

However, you still need to configure external resources like db conenctions, special config and so forth